# Column in field list is ambiguous when using INSERT INTO with field not even there

Tags: mysql

I can't believe I'm writing such a question but it is driving me mad. I'm getting the "Error Code: 1052. Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous" message on a query that has nothing to do with such an error!

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_micro_manufacturing` (
`id_ciccio` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`supplementation_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`manufacturing_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_ciccio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and here is the query

```
INSERT INTO `cantieri`.`test_micro_manufacturing` 
              (`id_ciccio`,`supplementation_id`,`manufacturing_id`,`name`) 
        VALUES(1,1,1,"ciao");
```

Please, help me make sense of how is it possible to get an error on a field that does not even exist on the table, especially when doing an INSERT INTO!
Thank you for any help, I appreciate it.
EDIT:
Here's the sequence to reproduce the error:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
use test_db;
CREATE TABLE ...
INSERT INTO ....
```

So the error is executed on a new database, with no triggers present.

Comment: Why do you think this query is the source of the error? Also maybe there is a trigger on inserts on this db which causes the error?

Comment: Because I created the table on a new clean database, and every time I use that query the error is raised. So no other explanation really.

Comment: @MicheleGrisafi the error you are facing has nothing to do with this query, check triggers with `show triggers ;` or check if it is another query/sp giving the error

Comment: "show triggers;" returns an empty set.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wATstWUpio4bdhsuxfkc4z/0 works like expected

Comment: I found the issue: it was indeed a trigger (thank you guys) defined on a different database (apparently they are valid for all databases). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggested, the issue was in a trigger defined on another database.